# Ubuntu Deployment No Class Def Exception Selenium

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, selenium, compiler-construction

I've been struggling for a few days now trying to figure out why I cant run a scheduled executor that uses selenium web driver on linux By using a war deployment. So far I have been able to get the project to work on my windows using eclipse and a maven project but when i go to the directory where it is deployed and type java -cp . ExecutorSchduler I get the following error? Could someone please provide some pointers as to what My issue could be? Let me know if you need more information

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-           instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-      4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>StillwaterApi</groupId>
      <artifactId>StillwaterApi</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>LATEST</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: What are the servers you are using un Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Window7/Tomcat7 Ubuntu13/Tomcat7

Comment: Can you do a maven clean install and investigate if you have org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver in any of the jars in your local .m2 repository?

Comment: Yeah, they are both present in the repository